# jQuery Validation plugin custom method. Multiple parameters

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

I'm trying to use a custom validator with jQuery Validation plugin.
However, I'm unsure how are you supposed to pass multiple arguments to a validation method?
I've tried using (2,3), curly braces and combinations, but I have failed.

This is the code - ???? marks the area I need info about:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
        jQuery.validator.addMethod("math", function(value, element, params) {
            return this.optional(element) || value == params[0] + params[1];
        }, jQuery.format("Please enter the correct value for {0} + {1}"));

        $("#form_register").validate({
            debug: true,
            rules: {
                inputEl: { required: true, math: ???? }
            },
            messages: {
                inputEl: { required: "Required", math: "Incorrect result" }
            }
        });
});
```

Answer (score 46, accepted):

Javascript arrays:

```
[value1,value2,value3]
```

SO your code might be:

```
inputEl: { required: true, math: [2, 3 ,4 , 5] }
```

Answer (score 26):

You can also pass a normal JavaScript object as a parameter which I personally find easier to work with:

```
jQuery.validator.addMethod("myRule", function (value, element, options) {
    return value === options.data;
}, "My Rule says no!");

$("#input").rules("add", { myRule: { data: "foo" } });
```

Comment: One drawback of this is that then you cannot use parameterized error messages. This plugin automatically formats error message with given value or parameters, so you can have error message "Please select more than {0} items" and it will automatically replace "{0}" with input's value (of with first parameter). So if parameter is an object, it won't work. And having multiple parameters you can have more user friendly error messages, for example in range situation, where params[0]  could be lower range value nad params[1] upper range value.