# jQuery Validation. Applying javascript logic (OR) to a custom rule

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

I've written the following simple rule for jQuery Validation:

```
        jQuery.validator.addMethod("notEqual", function(value, element, param) 
        {
          return this.optional(element) || value != param;
        }, "This field is required");
```

This works such that I can say:

```
        $("#form").validate({
                rules: 
                {
                    field1: {notEqual: "Please Select", required: true},
                    field2: {notEqual: "Year", required: true}
                },
                messages: 
                {
                    field1: {
                            notEqual: "This field is required", 
                            required: "This field is required"
                            }
                    field2: {
                            notEqual: "This field is required", 
                            required: "This field is required"
                            }
                },

                submitHandler: function(form) {
                form.submit();
            }
        });
```

However I want to be able to say that any one field is not allowed to be equal to multiple things e.g.

```
field1: {notEqual: "Please Select" || "Year" || "Some Value", required: true},
```

But I have tried this syntax as well as a few other ways of arranging the "ÖR" operator and none of them work. Can anyone help? Thanks.

Comment: the values that you don't want to match ( "Please Select", "Year", "Some Value") where are they coming from?  Are they values of other form fields or are they fixed text values?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass a JavaScript array as a parameter to a validation method, as described in the answer to [jQuery Validation plugin custom method. Multiple parameters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1366858/jquery-validation-plugin-custom-method-multiple-parameters)

for instance

```
field1: {notEqual: ["Please Select", "Year", "Some Value"], required: true},
```

then have your custom method something like this

```
 jQuery.validator.addMethod("notEqual", function(value, element, param) 
 {
  var result = value != param[0] && value != param[1] && value != param[2]; 
  return this.optional(element) || result;
 }, "This field is required");
```